# Spring multiple beans with same id in a factory pattern?

Tags: spring, factory, spring-data-neo4j

I have a two beans with the same id as thats the Neo4j Class it maps to internally so i can't have the id changed for both. Now for a clustered environment I need this bean:

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbBuilderFinal"
        factory-method="newGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown" />
```

And for a non-clustered one I need this :

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean"
        destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
<constructor-arg value="${neo4j.database.path}" />
</bean>
```

Right now I comment either one of them based on environment as not all environments will have cluster setup. Is there a way where as based on environment value(a property may be) it picks one bean among these.

This is how it is used in java class.

```
@Autowired
private GraphDatabaseService graphDB;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use spring profile feature (since spring 3.1.X) [see link](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/)

e.g

```
<beans profile="cluster">
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbBuilderFinal"
        factory-method="newGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown" /> 
</beans>

<beans profile="no_cluster">
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean"
        destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
<constructor-arg value="${neo4j.database.path}" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

and active the profile in your application in this way

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="cluster"
```

Will be loaded only the beans without profile and all those with the profile activated.
I hope this solution can help to solve your problem.

Comment: After moving these to separate xmls i am getting as error on starup Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'graphDatabaseService' is defined. May be not able to import these? I changed tomcat startup to set the profile like this.. something i am missing? -Dspring.profiles.active="no_cluster" call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS% :end

Comment: At this [link](http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/03/27/spring-3-1-profiles-and-tomcat-configuration/) there is a tomcat configuration for spring profile

Comment: Tell us if everything works.. if not, i help you to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Xstian! That helped, though setenv was a cleaner soln but did not work, may be because I am on windows m/c and I had setenv.bat instead. But setting it in catalina.bat worked.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to define with different Id´s just in different xml configuration files. Like

cluster.xml --->

```
  <bean id="graphDatabaseService" factory-bean="graphDbBuilderFinal"
    factory-method="newGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown" />
```

no_cluster.xml

```
  <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean"
    destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
```

And then use Spring profile to load one file or another depending of the profile

```
        <beans profile="cluster">
    <import resource="spring/cluster.xml" />
</beans>
<beans profile="no_cluster">
   <import resource="spring/no_cluster.xml" />
</beans>
```

Comment: After moving these to separate xmls i am getting as error on starup Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'graphDatabaseService' is defined. May be not able to import these?  I changed tomcat startup to set the profile like this.. something i am missing?
-Dspring.profiles.active="no_cluster"

call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end

Comment: Are you using Maven?. Normally I pass the profile by Maven.

Comment: Glad to heard it. If you consider useful response and resolve your issue, dont forget to vote and mark the answer as finish